# La etiqueta <ui: insert> no funciona

Tags: java, jsf

Estoy tratando de mostrar una parte de cada pagina xhtml con el **ui:insert name=""/>** pero no me aparece nada.

**Inicio.xhtml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<h:body>
    <h1>Inicio</h1>

    <ui:insert name="alumno"/>
    <ui:insert name="profesor"/>
    <ui:insert name="escuela"/>
</h:body>
</html>
```

**Alumnos.xhtml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

    <ui:composition template="/Inicio.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="alumno">
            <h1>Alumnos</h1>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>

</body>
</html>
```

**Escuelas.xhtml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <ui:composition template="/Inicio.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="escuela">
            <h1>Escuelas</h1>       
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</body>
</html>
```

**Profesores.xhtml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <ui:composition template="/Inicio.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="profesor">
            <h1>Profesores</h1>     
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</body>
</html>
```

**Lo que me aparece cuando ejecuto la página**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No sé si es la causa (de hecho no puedo ver la imagen por cuestiones técnicas), pero **siempre** debes usar *h:head* y *h:body* en vez de *head* y *body*.